# ¿Cómo hacer que el día introducido se añada al UPDATE?

Tags: mysql, python

estoy intentando hacer que en una columna llamada "Domingo" me guarde los datos ya dados.

Si coloco `Domingo=%s` y borro del `"hora=(dia, hora1, id_d)"` el `dia`, me funciona correctamente.

Pero quiero que funcione con la variable `dia` ya que tengo diferentes columnas y iré agregando números en cada una de ellas según introduzca en la variable `dia` (por ejemplo, luego añadiré "lunes"). No sé si me di a entender.

Programa:

```
dia="Domingo"
hora1=6
id_d=2
sql="UPDATE dias_registrado SET %s=%s WHERE id=%s"
hora=(dia, hora1, id_d)
mycursor.execute(sql, hora)
basedatos.commit()
print(mycursor.rowcount,"insertado")
```

Error:

```
Se produjo una excepción: ProgrammingError
1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Domingo'=6 WHERE id=2' at line 1
```

Es un error muy simple tal vez para ustedes, pero ya no tengo ideas de qué hacer.

Comment: Saludos, es mejor que agregues tu codigo en lugar de capturas con el fin de poder reproducir el mismo y darte una posible solucion, para ello edita tu pregunta "https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/250935/edit"

Comment: Hola, ya lo hice.

Comment: Me da la sensación de que le estás pasando unas comillas y un espacio de más. Puede ser?

Por el error que se muestra en la segunda imagen `''Domingo' =6 WHERE id=2'` es lo que más me llama la atención..

Comment: Es que no entiendo de dónde saca las comillas si no es una lista, tupple, set o diccionario. No encuentro el error.

Comment: Prueba con la opción del compañero @Diego Avila a ver si es la forma de insertar las variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos puedes realizar algo asi:

```
cursor.execute ("UPDATE dias_registrado SET %s=%s WHERE id='%s' " % (campo_dia, dia, id))
```

Tambien puedes revisar la documentacion: [MySql Python](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html)

Comment: No sé aún cómo pero me ha funcionado.

Comment: Ahora ayúdenme a ver cómo se cierra esto. Soy muy nuevo.

Comment: para determinar si la respuesta fue efectiva o es correcta debes dar click en la flecha que estara jnto a la respuesta y luego se pondra color verde lo cual significa que ha sido contestada satisfactoriamente @GeraldCaraballo